# WPF styling custom control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class that inherits from `TextBox`

```
public class DecimalTextBox : TextBox
{

    #region Float Color 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FloatColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FloatColor", typeof(Color), typeof(DecimalTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Colors.Red));
    public Color FloatColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(FloatColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FloatColorProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    . . . . ..  OTHER STUFF
}
```

I want to style this control using something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="DecimalTextBoxGridStyle" TargetType="DecimalTextBox">
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    <Setter Property="FloatColor" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>
```

But it style told me

[image]

**DecimalTexbox type isn't admited in wpf project**

How can I do to that ?

There is another approach ?

Comment: What about `{x:Type ns:DecimalTextBox}` where `ns` is the namespace containing `DecimalTextBox`?

Comment: I'm going to try it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include the XAML namespace:

```
<Style x:Key="DecimalTextBoxGridStyle" TargetType="local:DecimalTextBox">
```

where `local` is mapped to the CLR namespace in which the `DecimalTextBox` class is defined:

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```